# Image Stitching: Opencv SeamFinder returns patchy masks

Tags: c++, opencv, image-stitching

I have a setup of 6 cameras (60° horizontal and vertical FoV) with the same center looking outwards with a horizontal rotation of 30 degrees. I am projecting the images onto a sphere and the cameras are located in the center of which, see sketch below.

[image: simplified camera positioning sketch, look from on top of sphere]

I am stitching the images together close to this diagram from opencv, but because I know the orientation of the cameras I skip the "registration" part and (for now) omit the blending of the images.

[image: image stitching pipeline from opencv]

My problem is, that the masks returned by the SeamFinder are nonsense. I think it should work, because if I use `NoSeamfinder` in the simulation the results look good, but I tried every other Seamfinder OpenCV provides and the results are as shown below:
[image: SeamFinder Results]

I have worked with the stitching_detailed.cpp example from opencv to set up the pipeline but I have no idea what might be the issue. I thought that maybe, because I am working within a simulation, the gradients in the images are too sharp to work with, so I applied a Gaussian blur, which did not change anything.

I have some code snippets below and can post more on demand, but I want to avoid just dumping a whole load here.

I work with `cv::Mat` in the code and transform them to `cv::UMat` for the SeamFinder.

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> warped_images_mat;        // the single images are warped according to the sphere
std::vector<cv::UMat> warped_images_umat;

std::vector<cv::Mat> warped_masks_mat;         // Masks of the warped images within the sphere image
std::vector<cv::UMat> warped_masks_umat;

std::vector<cv::Mat> warped_masks_fixed_mat;   // These masks are calculated once and used to refresh the masks for the SeamFinder
std::vector<cv::UMat> warped_masks_fixed_umat;

std::vector<cv::Point> corners;                // position of the imgs and masks in the sphere image

cv::Ptr<cv::detail::SeamFinder> seam_finder = cv::makePtr<cv::detail::GraphCutSeamFinder>(cv::detail::GraphCutSeamFinderBase::COST_COLOR_GRAD);

// within the ROS2 callback:

this->warped_masks_umat.clear();  // clear the old masks
for(size_t cam_idx = 0; cam_idx < 6; cam_idx++){
        int cols = this->warped_images_mat.at(cam_idx).cols;
        int rows = this->warped_images_mat.at(cam_idx).rows;
        
        // std::cout << "rows: " << rows << "; cols: " << cols << std::endl;
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
                if (this->warped_masks_fixed_mat.at(cam_idx).at<u_char>(row, col) != 0)
                    // code to refresh warped image
        this->warped_images_mat.at(cam_idx).getUMat(cv::ACCESS_RW).convertTo(this->warped_images_umat.at(cam_idx), CV_32F);
        this->warped_masks_umat.push_back(this->warped_masks_fixed_umat.at(cam_idx).clone());
}

seam_finder->find(this->warped_images_umat, this->corners, this->warped_masks_umat);
```

Comment: I worked quite a bit with the (python bindings) of the stitching module. One thing I noticed that the seam masks improve significantly when cropping the warped images to a regular shape (which removes the black area around the final image). Maybe you want to try if you get better results if you crop the warped images to the same height. You can read more [here](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching_tutorial/blob/master/docs/Stitching%20Tutorial.md#seam-masks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mixed up the notations from opencv. The `.x` and `.y` from `cv::Point` were exchanged. It worked like this for refreshing the incoming images but were the wrong way round for the `SeamFinder`.

I noticed this when I tried to reproduce an example from the comment I got and noticed a distinctive shape in the masks. It works now also with the full masks, without cropping anything.